# Updating SMTP values and keystore file in project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning how to generate OTP value  generation and Online Banking application through Spring MVC but stuck on the 2 details

1. what values to be inserted in SMTP.properties
2. Code to be put in `Keystore.jks`

I have gotten confused about which value to be put into  the following fields:

1. `username=`
2. `password=`
3. `secret=`
   in `SMTP.properties`
   I need to figure out about code of `Keystore.jks`

**LINK OF GITHUB PROJECT**----> https://github.com/ajkulkarni/online-banking-application

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the body of your question in the form of a [Minimal, Complete Viable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Dumping a link to a repo is not helpful.